# Do teams connected SharePoint sites not support direct access/advanced permission management?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, administration, groups

Do teams connected SharePoint sites not support direct access/advanced permissions management?

Link: [Overview of Teams and SharePoint integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/teams-connected-sites#teams-connected-sites-and-channel-types?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).

Above link has a table wherein for sharing it only mentions about link sharing. Does this mean that it isn't possible to setup direct access permissions?

Comment: HI @variable, does my below answer help you with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to manage SharePoint site permissions separately from the Microsoft 365 group by using SharePoint groups (advanced permissions settings).

If you want users to have access to related group services/resources, it is advised to add users in the group instead of directly adding to SharePoint advanced permissions.

But if user needs access to *only* SharePoint site resources, it is possible using advanced permissions.

[image]

**Reference**: [Sharing and permissions in the SharePoint modern experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/modern-experience-sharing-permissions?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)